# Как подключить jQuery File Upload Django к существующей модели?

Tags: python, django

В [jQuery File upload django](https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload) есть пример реализации. Все работает, все ок, но вот вопрос, как это все подключить к собственной модели. Например, у нас есть модель заказа и в форме добавления заказа к полю filefield хочу прикрутить собственно это чудо https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload, где я хочу добавлять фотографии именно таким способом, чтобы можно было выбрать несколько, удалить, видеть статус бар и т.д. Т.е. файлы должны добавляться к определенному заказу. Или может посоветуете другой плагин, подходящий для этих целей.